# I need to generate a 32 digit random number using lua, please suggest some way

Tags: random, lua, unique

I want to generate a 32 digit key containing alphanumeric characters and they should always be UNIQUE. Please suggest a way of doing that.

I've used math.random function but I get the same random number over and over again, i want it to be unique.

Comment: You can use math.random for this, but you may have to set the seed, perhaps by using os.time. But be aware that the underlying engine is most propably not suitable for security applications.
Considering the way of generating the alphanumeric key: what have you tried. Please show us that.

Comment: What do you mean by *unique*? Compared to what? There are only finite number of 32 digit keys, so they can't always be unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a unique number you have to have a list of used numbers. Otherwise you will always have the chance of getting a used number again. Although it is quite unlikely with 32 digits.

You obviously did not read the documentation on `math.random`:
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.random

Otherweise you would know that `math.random` will always give you the same pseudo random numbers unless you change the seed value using `math.randomseed`...

Please make sure to read the documentation on functions befor you use them.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial program below generates 1000 random 32-bit keys without repetion with no wasted effort:

```
M=2^32-1
R={}
N=1000
n=0

for i=1,N do
    local x=math.random(M)
    if R[x]==nil then n=n+1 R[x]=n print(n,i,n==i,x) end
end
```

The point is that `M` is so large that repetitions are very unlikely, even if we increase `N` to one million.

Comment: Repetitions become quite probable starting with sqrt(M).  So, repetition will be very likely to happen at least once for N=10^6

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I've added `math.randomseed(os.time())` at the top and run several times with `N=1e6`. Not a single repetition... Of course, this may say something about the underlying random generator...

Comment: IMO, it is impossible.  The probability of having zero repetitions is about `exp(-0.5*N*N/M)`.  Bad statistical properties of PRNG should even more increase repetitions frequency.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, it works in Lua 5.2 (which uses `rand`) but not in 5.3 (which uses POSIX `random`)...

Comment: Add `print(N, n, n==N)` to the end of your program to see real result ;-) After the first repetition all attempts to generate a number are also repetitions that's why you dont see `false` printed.